# how to do coloring of string in eclipse plugin development

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

I am developing a plug-in.using my wizard we can create a new file with extension       "file name.xyz" and in that wizard we have radio buttons. it will choose strings and that string will print on the created file' editor. and that is done by string buffer reader. but now I need to store that string as array list and need to give specific colour to that string when it is shown in the editor

Comment: If you mean you want to do something like syntax coloring in an Eclipse editor this is a complex subject. Start by reading the [help on Eclipse editors](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Feditors.htm&cp=2_0_13) which covers syntax coloring.

Comment: actualy i need to do syntax coloring. before doing that i just need to try some simple example.thats why i am trying this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple way to do syntax coloring in an Eclipse editor you have to learn the full system.

If you create a new plug-in project one of the examples that Eclipse offers to create for you is an XML editor which contains most of the code you will need.

To create this run `New > Project > Plug-in Project`. On the second page of the new plug-in project wizard make sure you have `This plug-in will make contributions to the UI` set and `Would you like to create a 3.x rich client application` set to `No`. The next page of the wizard will then offer to `create a plug-in using one of the templates` - choose `Plug-in with a editor`.

Study this in conjunction with the [help of Eclipse editors](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Feditors.htm&cp=2_0_13)

Comment: i tried plugin with an editor.. again i have doubts actualy i create xml files and give some tags.. but its not have any color change

Comment: i run it as eclipse aplication and create new file with extension xml.. is it any proper way to create the xml file.

Comment: Check that `Open With` says `Sample XML Editor`.